# Breaking a parameter and save the items separately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to save items separately coming from a form of a text field, but my code is saving these items duplicate form.

**My controller**

```
def create

  @answer_option = AnswerOption.break_options(answer_option_params)
  @answer_option = AnswerOption.new(answer_option_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @answer_option.save
      format.html { redirect_to @answer_option, notice: 'Answer option was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @answer_option }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @answer_option.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**My model**

```
class AnswerOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question

  def self.break_options(var)
    ugly_answers = var[:content].split /[\r\n]+/
    ugly_answers.each do |answer|
      AnswerOption.create!(content: answer)
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the value of 
answer_option_params and also why you need to save twice as 'AnswerOption.new(answer_option_params) ' in controller and AnswerOption.create!(content: answer) in model

Comment: I believe this is also wrong

Comment: So you're saving them twice. Don't do that. Either one way or another.

Comment: Yes, but how to get my code?

Comment: "how to get my code" - It's actually pretty easy. You just have to decide what _exactly_ code should do and then you just type it out. Works every time. But for this to start working, some learning/education might be necessary. It's hard to do this when you don't know what half of your code does.

Comment: In method `break_options` i treating one of the parameters, but has another that also need to save.

Comment: How can I put it all together and save these two parameters that comes form the same instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
  @answer_option = AnswerOption.break_options(answer_option_params)
end
```